# fancybox with image_tag and link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

Im using fancybox within my app for a gallery. All my images are stored in my model and I can display them like so

```
<div class="container">
 <% @portfolio.each do |l| %>
  <div class="four columns">
   <div class="our-work">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#">
     <%= image_tag(l.url_large, :size => "220x220") %>
    </a>
    <h3><%= truncate(l.title, :length => 20) %></h3>
   </div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

What I am having trouble with is assigning the href so that when i click on an image a larger version of that same image is shown in a popup (fancybox).has anyone done this before or can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Normally if i want to link to the object itself i would do something like this

```
<%= link_to, l %>
```

Can I do the same as what I am using now but just change the size

```
<%= link_to, image_tag(l.url_large, :size => "480x480"), :class="fancybox %>
```

Not really sure how to fit it all together

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can do:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(l.url_large size: '220x220'), l.url_large, :class => 'fancybox', :rel => 'group' %>
```

or:

```
<%= link_to (l.url_large), :class => 'fancybox', :rel => 'group' do %>
  <%= image_tag(l.url_large, size: '220x220') %>
<% end %>
```

This will display image in its original size after clicking.

Comment: thanks, getting some syntax errors C:/Sites/flickr_1/app/views/pages/portfolio.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
....append=  link_to (l.url_large, :size => '480x480'), :class ...